# How can I do reversed dictionary for every value and a key in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert this dictionary:

```
dict1={x: ['John', 'Jack'], y: ['Julia', 'Michael']}
```

to this form:

```
 dict2={'Julia': y, 'John': x,  'Jack': x, 'Michael': y}
```

I researched that a lot but I could not find anything.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple operation, and it is not recommended to use multi-loop dictionary analysis. In general, you should try to keep the code simple and easy to read when it is not necessary. If there is a key conflict between the dictionaries, you should also write comments to ensure that others can fully understand.

```
new_dict = {}
for value, keys in dict1.items():
    for key in keys:
        new_dict[key] = value
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy as pie using a [Dictionary Comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension):

```py
dict1 = {'x': ['John', 'Jack'], 'y': ['Julia', 'Michael']}
dict2 = {'Julia': 'y', 'John': 'x',  'Jack': 'x', 'Michael': 'y'}
dict3 = {
    elem: key
    for key, list_value in dict1.items()
    for elem in list_value
}
assert dict2 == dict3
```

You're welcome.
However, please not that if one of the letters appear in several lists, only the last occurrence will be taken into account, for example:

```py
dict1 = {'x': ['Jack'], 'y': ['Jack']}
dict3 = {
    elem: key
    for key, list_value in dict1.items()
    for elem in list_value
}
print(dict3)  # {'Jack': 'y'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get all the values from dict1 as your new keys then iterate over the dict1 and test if you key exists in the values of key-dict1.

```
keys = [element for val in list(dict1.values()) for element in val]
dict2 = dict()
for key in dict1.keys():
    for k in keys:
        if k in dict1.get(key):
            dict2[k] = key
dict2
```

output

```
{'Julia': y, 'John': x,  'Jack': x, 'Michael': y}
```

Comment: dict2 is a new dictionnary. Inside the loop, to add a new element (key:val) I used dict2[k]=key to add the value 'key' to the 'k' key

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `itertools`:

```
import itertools

dict2 = dict(itertools.chain.from_iterable([zip(v,len(v)*k) for k, v in dict1.items()]))
```